# 2nd parameter "Arguments" of IApplicationActivationManager::ActivateApplication() syntax

Tags: c++, visual-c++, windows-store-apps, microsoft-metro, windows-mobile

I'm using IApplicationActivationManager::ActivateApplication() from [MSDN ActivateApplication API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh706903(v=vs.85).aspx)

to write a console app EXE (VC++) which launches a "Photos metro app & displays a PNG image". Here is teh code snippet. It's activating the "Photos metro application" but not able to display the image using the "Photos app".

```
CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_MULTITHREADED);
    LPCWSTR appId = L"Microsoft.Windows.Photos_8wekyb3d8bbwe!App";
    LPCWSTR imageArg = L" C:\\data\\Users\\Public\\Pictures\\image123.png";
    IApplicationActivationManager* paam = NULL;
    HRESULT hr = E_FAIL;

    __try
    {
        hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_ApplicationActivationManager, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_PPV_ARGS(&paam));
        if (FAILED(hr))
        {
            cout << "Error creating CoCreateINstance & HR is" <<hr<< endl;
            return 0;
        }

        DWORD pid = 0;
        hr = paam->ActivateApplication(appId, imageArg, AO_NONE, &pid);
        if (FAILED(hr))
        {
            cout << "Error in ActivateApplication call & HR is " <<hr<< endl;
            return 0;
        }

        cout << hex << hr;
        if (hr == 0)
            wprintf(L"Activated  %s with pid %d\r\n", appId, pid);
    }
    __finally
    {
        if (paam) paam->Release();
    }

    CoUninitialize();
```

I'm sure the error is in the 2nd argument of the "ActivateApplication()" function, where I'm giving the argument. I tried different ways of giving arguments like :

> LPCWSTR imageArg = L"
>   C:\data\Users\Public\Pictures\image123.png";      OR
>   LPCWSTR imageArg = L"-
>   C:\data\Users\Public\Pictures\image123.png";
>    LPCWSTR
>   imageArg = L"C:\data\Users\Public\Pictures\image123.png";

Comment: Yes i actually used "\\".

Comment: Your program terminates too quickly, making the string invalid by the time the target app is ready to retrieve the command line argument.  You must use CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER instead.  Always explain what you *really* want to accomplish when you ask a question, that way you are most likely to get the help you need.  And read the site license, attribution is required here.

Comment: i tried using CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER but this time it's failing in CoCreateInstance() itself.

Answer (score 1):

To perform a file activation use the [IApplicationActivationManager::ActivateForFile](http://IApplicationActivationManager::ActivateForFile%20method) method.

You can create a ShellItem from a file path with [SHCreateItemFromParsingName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762134(v=vs.85).aspx) (the path is a parsing name) and can create a ShellItemArray from that with
[SHCreateShellItemArrayFromShellItem](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762147(v=vs.85).aspx)

The Photos app won't listen for a file name on ActivateApplication's activation argument, and it wouldn't have access to the file by path if it did. The ActivateForFile method will convert the passed in ShellItems to StorageFiles which carry permissions to allow the app to open them.

Comment: Can you please help with a code snippet ? and give some basics on what are these shell items  and their interfaces ?

Comment: I'm not near a dev machine and can't provide a code snippet from my phone. It should be straight forward from the docs I all ready linked: call SHCreateShellItemFromParsingName to get a ShellItem then ShCreateShellItemArray to create an array from it. Give it a try then come back with questions after that. You'll be fine long before I can write any code

Comment: @Rob Caplan: I ran into a problem invoking the Photos app using IApplicationActivationManager::ActivateForFile in a way that is pretty much identical to what you described here. If you get a chance, could you take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35395035/error-opening-file-in-win10-modern-app-launched-from-desktop-c? Thanks!