# Error opening file in Win10 Modern app launched from desktop C++

Tags: c++, windows-10, launching-application

I'm trying to open an image file with the Windows 10 Photos app (which is a 'modern' app) from desktop C++ using the following code (error checks omitted for simplicity):

```
DWORD pid;
CComPtr<IApplicationActivationManager> paam;
CoCreateInstance(CLSID_ApplicationActivationManager, NULL, CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER, IID_PPV_ARGS(&paam));
CoAllowSetForegroundWindow(paam, NULL);
paam->ActivateForFile(pwszAppUserModelId, psia, L"open", &pid);
```

`pwszAppUserModelId` is the app user model ID for the Photos app. `psia` is a pointer to an `IShellItemArray` that contains a single `IShellItem` for an image file (PNG).

`ActivateForFile` is returning error 0x80270255:

> 'This app has multiple extensions registered to support the specified contract. Activation by AppUserModelId is ambiguous.'

Any tips on how to fix this? TIA.

Comment: Did you try ShellExecute?

Comment: Yes. On a clean Win10 system (not an upgrade from Win7/8), ShellExecute fails, claiming that there is no association. And, in fact, there's no Shell/Open key under HKCR/pngfile (or any other image type).

Comment: Can you double-click a PNG file from Windows Explorer? Are you on a released build of Windows or an Insider flight?

Comment: Yes, if I double-click a PNG in Explorer, it opens in Photos. It's a released build of Windows 10 Enterprise.